# When using " " marks ? characters and Japanese/Chinese characters appear

Tags: html

I'm building a website for my English project on Joseph Stalin. Here is the link https://rgfv1b7yhdkrircg9h9ryg-on.drv.tw/Englisjh/topnav.html

As you can see when quotation marks appear a question mark appears or a weird character (I think is a Japanese or Chinese character). How can I fix this?

Comment: Your link is a 404.

Comment: Here is the code for the web page.

Comment: I checked the link with another device and it seems to be working

Comment: Are you logged in to any kind of account, that might be needed to see that page?

Comment: I'm not sure but I used my Drive account to post it on the internet.

Comment: However, try adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` into the `<head>` section of your page if you haven't yet.

Comment: Ok sounds great. Of course i have to save it as a UTF-8 encoding right.